# looking for a way to see what oauth scopes an app might ask for

Tags: android, oauth, scope, google-oauth

Im looking for a way to find out what oAuth scopes an app might ask for for accessing my google account without actually downloading the app and seeing what permissions the app is requesting.
currently i'm downloading the apk file and using a java decompiler i'm looking at what scopes the app is requesting,unfortunately, i'm currently only able to find the local scopes.but i'm looking for the oAuth scopes that request access to my google account (specifically my gdrive and google+).
any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry there is no way to find out other than asking the developer or asking other users of the app (or from their reviews). The reason is that these permissions can be invoked depending on what you do and the app could ask for different permissions later e.g. if at some point you want to save a file to the drive.. you may get a choice to save to dropbox or Google drive and depending on what you select it'll ask you for that permission.